# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Um relacionamento many to many entre a table Paciente e Doencas, e Paciente e Alergias estou com o seguinte problema.

```
pacientes_alergias = db.Table('pacientes_alergias',
    db.Column('paciente_id', Integer, ForeignKey('paciente.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('alergias.id', Integer, ForeignKey('alergias.id'), primary_key=True)
    )


pacientes_doencas = db.Table('pacientes_doencas',
    db.Column('paciente_id', Integer, ForeignKey('paciente.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('doencas.id', Integer, ForeignKey('doencas.id'), primary_key=True)
    )


class Paciente(Pessoa):
__tablename__ = 'paciente'
id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
doenca = relationship('Doencas', secondary=pacientes_doencas, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('pacientes', lazy=True), uselist=True)
alergia = relationship('Alergias', secondary=pacientes_alergias, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('pacientes', lazy=True), uselist=True)

class Alergias(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'alergias'
id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
alergia = db.Column(String(30), unique=True)

class Doencas(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'doencas'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    doenca = db.Column(String(30), unique=True)
```

O problema é que quando realizo inclusão de alergia no paciente, ela ocorre sem problema, mas inclusão de doenças da erro.

```
p = Paciente()
p.alergia.append(Alergias.query.first())

p.doenca.append(Doencas.query.first())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Já com alergias, ele realiza o append sem problema. Indeendente do que eu faça, a doenca no paciente não realiza append, mesmo implementando ela como lista.

```
type(p.alergia)
sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList
```

```
type(p.doenca)
NoneType
```